# GA4 - User Id reports in GA4 and exploitation in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

**User Id implementation**

Hello everybody, I implemented the User Id tracking for GA4. I did it properly, I am pretty sure I am collecting it correctly because I can see User Id in Real time report and also in Add Comparison tool.

**I have 3 problems about how to exploit User Id in GA4 reports**

**#Problem 1**

I don´t figure how to exploit User Id as user_property or custom dimension in my reports. I tried to do it in the Aquisition report but the User Id column show me (not set) value everywhere. When I add comparison with the **Comparision tool** it shows me up all User Id numeric value in the column, against the (not set) value of the predifined column...

[image]

**#Problem 2**

I also tried to exploit User Id info in the **Hub analysis** tool but it also shows me all user id in (not set).

[image]

**#Problem 3**

I ended up thinking that GA4 doesnt allow to exploit User Id in it's own interface so I went through BigQuery. But I turned crazy today when I saw that in Bigquery my user_id field had been populated without any value, it shows me "null" in the table.

[image]

Could someone help me, I would just like to be able to create a report with a list of all User Id in a row (dimension) and total events count in columns (metrics). How could I do it?

Comment: What do you see in BigQuery if you do a `SELECT DISTINCT user_id`?

Comment: Yes, great it worked for me! Thank you very much. Damn, how could I forget to test it with a select distinct... jaja!

Comment: Do you have any info about User Id exploitation within GA4 user interface?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'exploitation'?

Comment: @MinhazKazi by exploitation y mean data exploitation, how to use User Id within GA4 report and Hub analysis section.